# Stop Safe Mode In Windows 7 on Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, graphics-card, aero

I would like to update the video card settings to allow aero mode on Windows 7 in Virtual Box but on the installation it says windows is in safe so aero mode won't work.

How do I take it out of safe mode?

Comment: Run `msconfig` and go to the Boot tab. If "Safe boot" is checked, uncheck it and reboot. If not, let us know, because something is very wrong.

Comment: It was already unchecked. There is something wrong.

Comment: Run SFC /SCANNOW from an admin command prompt and restart when done to see if SFC corrects the issue

Comment: Run: (1) `chkdsk`, (2) [sfc /scannow](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html), (3) verify disk SMART data by a utility such as [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy), (4) Check the Event Viewer.

Comment: It says you must be admin to run sfc but despite the fact iam.

Comment: From Safe Mode, can you make a new Administrator user?  Try that, restart as the new Administrator and see if you can run admin tasks.

Comment: I have done that and run the scan it says "Windows didn't find any integrity violations".  What shall I do next?

Comment: If you have done that and the disk is OK (Harry's test) then you may be at a place where it is faster to build a new image.  You can try repairing the system with the Windows 7 DVD but I have not tried this on a virtual machine.

Comment: You need to install the Guest Additions, its very likely you're not in safe mode, it's a false error message. You need to enable 3D acceleration and have more than 128MB of memory assigned in the display settings.

Comment: @essjae It wouldn't let me install 3D acceleration so how can I enable it?

Comment: You check the box on the settings of the VM for 3D acceleration, the VM must be turned off to change this (not running or in a saved state).  See: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/enable-windows-7-aero-effects-virtualbox/  for a screenshot of the settings needed

Comment: When you're installing the Guest Additions, make sure to check the 3D box, when it prompts you to install "Direct3D", click no, and just follow the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safe mode is likely a false error.

### Configure the Windows 7 VM

1. With the VM off, click to select it
2. Click **Settings**
3. Click **Display**
4. Increase **Video Memory** to at least **128MB**, preferably **256MB**
5. Check **Enable 3D acceleration**
6. Check **Enable 2D acceleration**
7. Click **OK**

[image]

### Start the Windows 7 VM and install the Guest Additions

1. Log in to Windows
2. From the VirtualBox menu, click **Devices\Insert Additions CD image**
3. Open Windows Explorer in the Windows 7 VM, click **Windows Explorer**
4. Click **Computer**
5. Double-click **CD Drive (D:) VirtualBox Guest Additions**
6. Double-click **VBoxWindowsAdditions**
7. Click **Yes** when prompted by UAC
8. The installer may be hidden, click the VirtualBox icon on the taskbar, if needed.
9. Click **Next** to start the Guest Additions Setup
10. Click **Next** to accept the default location
11. Check **Direct3D Support** and click **Install**.
12. Click **No** when prompted to install basic Direct3D support.
    [image]
13. Click **OK** to acknowledge the memory requirements
14. Click **Install**
15. Reboot the Windows 7 VM

### Enable Aero in Display Settings

1. Right-click on the Desktop and then click **Personalize**
2. Click on one of the **Aero Themes** to enable Aero

[image]